# Error while building geonode client using github?

Tags: git

```
$ git clone git://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-client.git geonode-client
$ cd geonode-client
$ ant init debug
```

The error I get is this

```
Buildfile: build.xml

init:
     [echo] pulling in ringo (ignore fatal warning)
     [exec] fatal: destination directory '.' already exists.
     [exec] Result: 128
     [exec] From git://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-client
     [exec]  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
     [exec] Already up-to-date.
     [exec] error: pathspec 'build/ringo/e0dce2be640fc6fb43a1239d252948d10687ba9c' did not match any file(s) known to git.

BUILD FAILED
/home/palantir/geonode1/src/geonode-client/build.xml:22: exec returned: 1
```

How do I debug this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant lines of the [`build.xml`](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-client/blob/master/build.xml) are:

```
   <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
   <echo message="pulling in ringo (ignore fatal warning)"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build}/ringo"/>
    <exec executable="git" dir="${build}/ringo" failonerror="false">
        <arg line="clone -nq git://github.com/ringo/ringojs.git ."/>
    </exec>
    <exec executable="git" dir="${build}/ringo" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="pull origin master"/>
    </exec>
    <exec executable="git" dir="${build}/ringo" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="checkout e0dce2be640fc6fb43a1239d252948d10687ba9c"/>
    </exec>
```

The problem comes from the failure to clone the ringo repo in the current `${build}/ringo`.

That can be the case for:

- git previous to 1.6, which didn't process well the '.' current directory with `git clone`.
  (So what version of Git are you using?)
- non-empty directory ("Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty"), which shouldn't be the case since `${build}` is just created above.
  Still double check the value of `${build}` and make sure it is actually empty.